# Servertag format wrong

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a gridview where I try to set the visibility for 2 buttons and a label and also the text of the label via commands in the aspx file itself.

Now I've run into the problem that regardless if I use <%# or <%= or <% I always get "servertag format wrong".

Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button runat="server" text="Freigeben" Visible="<%#!IsEnvelopeCleared((String)Eval("Status")) %>"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" text="Ablehnen" Visible="<%#!IsEnvelopeCleared((String)Eval("Status")) %>"/>
    <asp:Label runat="server" text="<%# Bind("Status") %>" Visible="<%# IsEnvelopeCleared((String)Eval("Status")) %>"/>
```

The error appears on the first <%# already (I also tried removing the ! to no avail).

Comment: `Visible='<%# !IsEnvelopeCleared((String)Eval("Status")) %>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall double quote is the problem.

You have to use single quote. Following is one of the line from your code.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" text="Freigeben" Visible='<%#!IsEnvelopeCleared((String)Eval("Status")) %>'/>
```

Comment: that was it tnx. still though as double quote is what is created by default....is that always with asp.net that " has a different behaviour than ' ?

Comment: Yes. If you only use Like Visible="false" then it is fine but when you put expression and like Eval also contains double quote so it create problem.